# A Very Simple Question about Probability

Tags: probability

I'm self-studying an MIT OpenCourseware Probability Course, and I came across something I can't understand in conditional probability.

John Tsitsiklis's book quite literally quotes in choosing an appropriate sample space, "different elements of the sample space should be distinct and mutually exclusive. For example, the sample space associated with the roll of a die cannot contain '1 or 3' as a possible outcome, because we would not be able to assign a unique outcome  when the roll is a '1'."

Conditional probability says that P(A|B) = P(A∩B)/P(B). So in the question, what is P(the outcome is 6|the outcome is even), isn't defining events A and B contradicting this rule for events being mutually exclusive, or is this allowed in problems of conditional probability?

For example, if we define A = {6}, B = {2, 4, 6}, these events aren't mutually exclusive but it clearly produces the right answer when you use them in the equation (which is obviously 1/3).

Can someone please clarify this for me? I don't understand why the textbook says a sample space must be defined as events being mutually exclusive if sometimes not all events will be mutually exclusive.

Thanks!

Comment: His says the *outcomes* should be well-defined.  This doesn't mean that events can't comprise various outcomes.

Comment: There are atomic events which are the basic outcomes and are mutually exclusive. And there are composite events which are sets of atomic events — eg the die lands on an even number. The word “event” is ambiguous and encompasses both atomic and composite events

Comment: I actually don’t see why “1 or 3” is not a valid member of a sample space for the roll of a die. The unique outcome in case the roll is a $1$ is “1 or 3.” That happens to make an awkward and less-than-usually-useful sample space; for example with that sample space you can’t describe the probability that the sum of two rolls will be $4$. But the fact that something is awkward and less useful than other things does not make it I’ll-defined.

Comment: You might not be ready for it, but you may be interested in reading about the concept of a [sigma-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra).  The set of all possible events in a probability space will be a sigma-algebra and the minimal nonempty sets correspond to the outcomes in the sample space.  As you eventually start to study actual probability *theory* as opposed to just how to use probability concepts, this is all very rigorously formalized using related concepts from measure theory.